# c# wpf Do I need to use mvvm pattern or some else? Can I work without it?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am short on time,and I need to develop a desktop app that will be used in a firm.
I dont have time to learn mvvm or any other design pattern.

Can I develop an app without it?
I did some basic sql crud with a table and it works fine,but I wanted to ask you if I can develop a whole app without some of this design patterns.

EDIT: You can do it,but you have to be carefull,also there will be more effort included if you want to edit some things down the line.

Comment: Of course you can.  Whether or not that app will be any good or reasonably supportable is another story entirely...

Comment: This particular SO board wasn't created with the intent of getting feedback on broad, opinion-based questions like this. However, you can definitely use any patterns (or lack thereof) you would like and successfully create a full app.

Comment: you can work with out it but if you don't go with it then you will be making things much harder for yourself as WPF is geared to run off binding and binding is designed around INotifyPropertyChanged which is MVVM

Comment: MVVM isn't really a lot to learn, and honestly your development would probably go faster with it. Some aspects you might already be doing in your WinForms development. I like to blog about beginner WPF things, and you might be interested in starting at [Transitioning from Winforms to WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15684569/302677).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You don't need to rely on MVVM when using wpf. Really the keys to
> using wpf properly are:
>
> -Use commands instead of events (you might do this without realizing
> it, but check to make sure)
>
> -Use data binding instead of getting values
> off of controls directly
>
> -Set the data context and bind to that instead
> of binding to the code behind
>
> MVVM works really well for these two
> things but is not required. Specifically, MVVM requires a 3-tier
> strict separation of concerns that can just as easily be done with
> MVP.

Source :

[Developing WPF software without MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863840/developing-wpf-software-without-mvvm)

Comment: Do I really need to use binding? Can I just get all the things that I need from sql querys placed in events?